# Python GUI text editor

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have a GUI text editor i made with tkinter. It currently opens, saves and clears the screen. I have added an encrypt and decrypt button and will eventually apply the ceasar cipher to whatever text is on the screen.
For my encrypt  button i so far have

```
def encrypt():
    text = editor.get(1.0, tk.END)
    encryptList = []
    for word in text:
        encryptList.append(word)
        
    random.shuffle(encryptList)
    return encryptList
```

What i am trying to have happen is to shuffle the text on my screen from whatever i have on there (im using a test file with "Test" printed a bunch of times) After I'm able to do this I can implement a cesar cipher to the text on the screen. (I hope)

whole code:

```
#Import Module
import random
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename, asksaveasfilename
from tkinter import ttk


#Create Function for New File Button
def fileNew():
    editor.delete(1.0, tk.END)

#Create Function For Open File Button
def fileOpen():
    editor.delete(1.0, tk.END)
    filepath = askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Text Files", "*.txt"), ("All Files", "*.*")])      
    with open(filepath, "r") as file:
        text = file.read()
        editor.insert(tk.END, text)
        
def encrypt():
    text = editor.get(1.0, tk.END)
    encryptList = []
    for word in text:
        encryptList.append(word)
        
    random.shuffle(encryptList)
    return encryptList
        
    
        
#Create Function For Save File Button
def fileSave():
    save = asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".*", filetypes=[("Text Files", "*.txt"), ("All Files", "*.*")])
    if not save:
        return
    with open(save, "w") as fileOutput:
        text = editor.get(1.0, tk.END)
        fileOutput.write(text)
        
        
        
#GUI
root = tk.Tk()
root.rowconfigure(0, minsize=500, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(1, minsize=800, weight=1)
#Title
root.title()



#Text Editor
editor = tk.Text(root)
editor.configure(background="#263D42")
editor.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")



#Scrollbar
scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(root, orient='vertical', command=editor.yview)
scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='ns')



#Left Side Panel
sidePanel = tk.Frame(root)
sidePanel.configure(background="#232e3a")
sidePanel.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ns")


#Open File Button
btn_open = tk.Button(sidePanel, text="Open", command=fileOpen)
btn_open.configure(background="#867c91")
btn_open.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ew", padx=5, pady=5)

#New File Button
btn_new = tk.Button(sidePanel, text="New", command=fileNew)
btn_new.configure(background="#867c91")
btn_new.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew", padx=5, pady=5)

#Encrypt File Button
btn_open = tk.Button(sidePanel, text="Encrypt", command=encrypt)
btn_open.configure(background="#867c91")
btn_open.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="ew", padx=5, pady=5)

#Decrypt File Button
btn_open = tk.Button(sidePanel, text="Decrypt")
btn_open.configure(background="#867c91")
btn_open.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="ew", padx=5, pady=5)

#Save Button
btn_saveas = tk.Button(sidePanel, text="Save As", command=fileSave)
btn_saveas.configure(background="#867c91")
btn_saveas.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky="ew", padx=5, pady=5)



root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You haven't asked a question, you've simply described what you're doing. What is the problem you're asking about?

Answer (score -1):

Closed. I figured it out

```
def encrypt():
    text = editor.get(1.0, tk.END)
    encryptList = []
    for word in text:
        encryptList.append(word)
        
    random.shuffle(encryptList)
```

needed to add

```
editor.delete(1.0, tk.END)
editor.insert(tk.END, encryptList)
```

Comment: Your question could do with a little explanation of the problem, and your answer could do with an explanation of the solution. All we know is that this code "works", and that the code in the question somehow didn't "work". See [ask] and [answer] for more information on asking good questions and answering them well.